# Read case class object from string in Scala (something like Haskell's "read" typeclass)

Tags: scala, haskell, serialization

I'd like to read a string as an instance of a case class. For example, if the function were named "read" it would let me do the following:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val personString: String = "Person(Bob,42)"
val person: Person = read(personString)
```

This is the same behavior as the read typeclass in Haskell.

Comment: I find the only present-day useful answers below, are the more recent ones describing pickling scala libraries: [the scala pickling library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23610675/1509695) and [uPickle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28173416/1509695).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

dflemstr answered more towards setting up the actual `read` method- I'll answer more for the actual parsing method.

My approach has two objects that can be used in scala's pattern matching blocks. `AsInt` lets you match against strings that represent `Int`s, and `PersonString` is the actual implementation for `Person` deserialization.

```
object AsInt {
  def unapply(s: String) = try{ Some(s.toInt) } catch {
    case e: NumberFormatException => None
  }
}

val PersonRegex = "Person\\((.*),(\\d+)\\)".r

object PersonString {
  def unapply(str: String): Option[Person] = str match {
    case PersonRegex(name, AsInt(age)) => Some(Person(name, age))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

The magic is in the `unapply` method, which scala has syntax sugar for. So using the `PersonString` object, you could do

```
val person = PersonString.unapply("Person(Bob,42)")
//  person will be Some(Person("Bob", 42))
```

or you could use a pattern matching block to do stuff with the person:

```
"Person(Bob,42)" match {
  case PersonString(person) => println(person.name + " " + person.age)
  case _ => println("Didn't get a person")
}
```

Comment: One nice trick I learned recently, is to use `import scala.util.control.Exception._` and then `catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).opt(s.toInt)` or even `allCatch.opt(s.toInt)`.

Comment: That is a pretty nice little language for exception handling. My problem with it is that for simple things like this, it doesn't really end up saving much in the way of typing, and it can be just another step in the way of a beginner's understanding of an example. That being said, you get my +1

Answer (score 8):

Scala does not have type classes, and in this case, you cannot even simulate the type class with a trait that is inherited from, because traits only express methods on an object, meaning that they have to be "owned" by a class, so you cannot put the definition of a "constructor that takes a string as the only argument" (which is what "read" might be called in OOP languages) in a trait.

Instead, you have to simulate type classes yourself. This is done like so (equivalent Haskell code in comments):

```
// class Read a where read :: String -> a
trait Read[A] { def read(s: String): A }

// instance Read Person where read = ... parser for Person ...
implicit object ReadPerson extends Read[Person] {
  def read(s: String): Person = ... parser for Person ...
}
```

Then, when you have a method that depends on the type class, you have to specify it as an implicit context:

```
// readList :: Read a => [String] -> [a]
// readList ss = map read ss
def readList[A: Read] (ss: List[String]): List[A] = {
  val r = implicitly[Read[A]] // Get the class instance of Read for type A
  ss.map(r.read _)
}
```

The user would probably like a polymorphic method like this for ease of use:

```
object read {
  def apply[A: Read](s: String): A = implicitly[Read[A]].read(s)
}
```

Then one can just write:

```
val person: Person = read[Person]("Person(Bob,42)")
```

I am not aware of any standard implementation(s) for this type class, in particular.

Also, a disclaimer: I don't have a Scala compiler and haven't used the language for years, so I can't guarantee that this code compiles.

Answer (score 8):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String`s by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
// case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
"Person(Bob,42)" match { case s"Person($name,$age)" => Person(name, age.toInt) }
// Person("Bob", 42)
```

---

Note that you can also use `regex`es *within* the extractor.

Which in this case, helps for instance to match on "Person(Bob, 42)" (age with a leading space) and to force age to be an integer:

```
val Age = "[ ?*](\\d+)".r

"Person(Bob, 42)" match {
  case s"Person($name,${Age(age)})" => Some(Person(name, age.toInt))
  case _ => None
}
// Person = Some(Person(Bob,42))
```

Answer (score 6):

The answers on this question are somewhat outdated. Scala has picked up some new features, notably typeclasses and macros, to make this more easily possible.

Using the [Scala Pickling library](https://github.com/scala/pickling), you can serialize/deserialize arbitrary classes to and from various serialization formats:

```
import scala.pickling._
import json._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val person1 = Person("Bob", 42)
val str = person1.pickle.value // { tpe: "Person", name: "Bob", age: 42 }
val person2 = JSONPickle(str).unpickle[Person]

assert(person1 == person2) // Works!
```

The serializers/deserializers are automatically generated at compile time, so no reflection! If you need to parse case classes using a specific format (such as the case class `toString` format), you can extend this system with your own formats.

Comment: The library does fall back to reflection, for above vanilla use cases.

Answer (score 1):

The [uPickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) library offers a solution for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Scala uses Java's serialization stuff, with no `String` representation.

Comment: Things have changed in the meantime, see DCKing's answer.