# Scala convert string to object

Tags: scala

I have class definition `case class Name(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String])` and a string `Name(Tom,Some(Bob))`, how can I convert the string to a `Name` object?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804581/read-case-class-object-from-string-in-scala-something-like-haskells-read-typ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to deconstruct the input string. (**Scala 2.13.0**)

```
case class Name(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String])

val str = "Name(Tom,Some(Bob))"

val nm :Name = str match {
  case s"Name($fn,Some($ln))" => Name(fn, Some(ln))
  case s"Name($fn,None)"      => Name(fn, None)
  case _ => throw new Error("not a name")
}
//nm: Name = Name(Tom,Some(Bob))
```

Comment: If my class contains `Seq` like `case class User(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String], addresses: Seq[Address])`, it will be difficult to assemble the regex because count of `Address` is unknown, any good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You appear to be looking for an `eval()` function, i.e. something like `myCodeRslt = eval(myString)` Scala can't do that. To get close you'd probably have to write a macro after digging in to the `reflection` library. Easier to simply switch to a different language.